# Can an ASP.NET MVC3 Controller be Sessionless if it's SessionStateBehavior is ReadOnly?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

If i set a controller's `SessionStateBehavior` to `ReadOnly`, does that give the same functionality -allowing async requests, instead of syncronous requests - per user? Or only the `Disabled` value does that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if the session is disabled or readonly for a given controller action this controller action could be invoked in parallel from the same session. You may checkout the [following blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/07/10/concurrent-requests-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx).